# How can you add your own Forth program and execute in the Mecrisp-Ice 0.8 -enhanced fork of Swapforth by James Bowman?

Tags: forth, gforth

I want to write LED blinking code in Forth. I have knowledge of the I/O peripherals address mapping of ICEstick or the Verilog code written for [Mecrisp-Ice 0.8](https://github.com/zuloloxi/mecrisp-ice). When I open nucleus.fs - the heart of the J1 CPU, I find ": main" and below are the words "2emit" which are used to send characters Mecrisp-Ice 0.8 serially.

Should I write the LED blinking program in this section?

Comment: please let me know in case the question isn't clear

Comment: Why don't you try and see if it fits your needs? `Swapforth` is a complete system, and it's expected that you load your Forth sources via serial connection, or from spi memory "sector" (that was added by Mecrisp project). But still you could alter it and add your calls in `main` word, if that really solves your task at hand.

Comment: You may try to redefine the "init" word